# Remote Query Cost - High Row Count

Tags: sql-server, performance, execution-plan, remote, query-performance

I have a query that calls a remote table through Linked Server.
However, in the execution plan the Remote Query is 71% of total cost and the time taken to run is over 4mins. It returns **all** rows in the remote table (Actual Number of Rows value is over 1 million).

If I run the remote query separately, the Actual Number of Rows value is 2.

Why does it load all rows?

Below is the subquery part that calls the remote tables...

[image]

[image]

If I run the remote query part (the subquery) in a new window, the Actual Number of Rows is 2, and time taken is 1 second...

[image]

Comment: I'd be curious to know if removing the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT makes any difference.

Comment: The sub query is from SQL 2012 so I need the COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT for it to work. The main query is on 2008R2

Comment: Have you tried rewriting your Linked Table SELECT using [`OPENQUERY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openquery-transact-sql)? You can push the `DISTINCT`, `JOIN` and `WHERE` filtering to the remote server, instead of downloading all the table rows and filtering them out on your local server.

Answer (score 1):

In versions of SQL Server earlier than 2012 (plus some patching), [Linked Server permissions needed SA privs to use statistics information](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2683304/an-update-is-available-for-sql-server-2012-that-changes-the-permission) when processing remote queries. That could be what's messing you up.

For more information, see Conor Cunningham's talk on [distributed queries here](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event10/Distributed_Query_Deep_Dive).